# Closing multiple modals in a Joomla Plugin

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin

I am trying to call an image popup box for a flexicontent plugin in J3.4.1.

[image: Problem]

The problem is - the insert & cancel don't seem to close the modal.

Code:

```
<div class="pull-right">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="window.parent.jInsertFieldValue(document.getElementById('f_url').value,'txtImgUrl');window.parent.jModalClose();">Insert</button>
<button class="btn" type="button" onclick="window.parent.jModalClose();">Cancel</button>
    </div>
```

When I call jModalClose:

```
function jModalClose() {
            window.parent.jModalClose();
        }
```

I get the following js error:
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

I am aware that bootstrap has issues with multiple modals:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/5022#issuecomment-10099093

But am unsure of how to close the module. Thanks.

Comment: This looks to be MooTools and jQuery conflict. See the below url to solve such issues. http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7648/javascript-errors-in-console-jquery-easy-jch-optimize/9858#9858